# python nested list access gives error in loop

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am currently stuck on this error and I did not find a solution (that I understood) on Google:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I try to do:

```
    for x in values:
        val1 = values[x][0]
        val2 = values[x][1]
        val3 = values[x][2]

        writer.writerow([val1,val2,val3])
```

`values` is a nested list.
Every nested list has the same length.

I understand the error, but I don't get why I am getting it because if i do: `print(values[400][0])`, everything works out fine, no error, just the content of the list.

Comment: if you are satisfied with one of the answers, request you to accept one of them as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `for x in values` where values is a `list`, `x` represent the elements so when you use `values[x]`, you are trying to access the `values` list by a list index which gives you the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

Try this code:

```
for x in values:
    val1 = x[0]
    val2 = x[1]
    val3 = x[2]

    writer.writerow([val1,val2,val3])
```

Or change your code to below to use index based access:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    val1 = values[i][0]
    val2 = values[i][1]
    val3 = values[i][2]

    writer.writerow([val1,val2,val3])
```

Comment: suggesting to use `range(len(values))` is not pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

By using `for x in values`, `x` will be the sublist of you `values` list. If you try to index your main list by calling `values[x]`, this will throw an error, as you can not index a list using a list.
What you want is this

```
for x in values:
        val1 = x[0]
        val2 = x[1]
        val3 = x[2]
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `for` loop: you need to write it like so to prevent the error:

```
for x in range(len(values)):
    val1 = values[x][0]
    val2 = values[x][1]
    val3 = values[x][2]

    writer.writerow([val1,val2,val3])
```

Better still, use this:

```
for x in values:
    writer.writerow([x[i] for i in range(3)])
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, `values` is a list of lists.

Example. = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [9,10,11]]

So when you do `for x in values:`, you are taking out each list one by one, so now the x is a simple list.
x = [1,2,3] in first iteration.

So, when you do `values[x][0]`, you are doing `values[[1,2,3]][0]`, which doesn't make sense, because list should be indexed with numbers.

Correct code would be

```
for x in values:
        val1 = x[0]
        val2 = x[1]
        val3 = x[2]
    writer.writerow([val1,val2,val3])
```